# Preventing leakage when train/test splitting time series?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, cross-validation, panel-data, dataset

Let's say I have a feature set `X` that is of size `m` x 2, where `m` are samples, and the two features are `timepoint` and `panel`. `timepoint` is a variable which ranges from 1 to 100, and represents the time at which the sample was taken, and `panel` is a categorical variable that is a unique identifier for each time series. My outcome variable `y` is of shape `m` x 1 and is a continuous variable. I want to train a regression model.

In other words, a small excerpt with timepoints 1-3 might look like:

```
y    timepoint    panel
1.5  1            1
5.4  2            1
6.7  3            1
3.3  1            2
3.4  2            2
4    3            2
```

How do I properly split this data into train/test, without resulting in leakage between the two sets?

1. Train/test split on `X`, ignoring the grouping variable (i.e.
   randomly take 33% of the rows in `X` as my test)?
2. Split based on the grouping variable (i.e. randomly take 33% of
   the groups in `panel`)?

My hunch is that #2 is the proper way to do this. Suggestions?

Comment: So panel is a categorical variable? how many groups does it have?

Comment: @horaceT Yes, panel is a categorical variable. It has thousands of levels, as it's a unique identifier for each timeseries.

Answer (score 2):

Your hunch is correct, if the "levels" of the panel variable are an **independent** random sample.